# What is device quota per day for Android c2dm?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

Does anyone know device quota per day for Android c2dm?

PS: Im not interesting in application quota that is 200 000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Device quota is 1000 per application per device. Here is [answer on Google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-c2dm/Ab6FYlxAxH4)

Answer (score 6):

C2DM quotas is indeed based both on number of messages to a device or messages sent for any device.

It doesn't however seem to be stated anywhere what the amounts for a single device is.

When you sign up you give an estimate of how many messages you expect your application to send. (And are assigned a default quota of 200,000)

You can read about the limitations of c2dm [here](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/#limitations)

And you can read about the quotas [here](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/quotas.html). Here you will also be able to request more than the default 200,000 messages.

Comment: The links you posted say there are both account AND Device quotas.

Comment: You are right the limitations link states that "Google limits the number of messages a sender sends in aggregate, and the number of messages a sender sends to a specific device."

Comment: CoolMc i know about application quota. The question is about device quota that is not documented by Google.

Comment: Ye i realised that after Bradleys comment. At first i thought that it was only based on the number of messages sent out, so i edited the "answer" to reflect that it indeed is also based on number of messages for a device.